# Gap of two surfaces in Plot3D

Tags: plotting

```
F = Sqrt[x^2+(y + I/2)^2];

Plot3D[Im[F], {x, 0, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
Mesh -> None, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][z + 0.5]],  
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
ViewPoint -> {2, -2, 1.5}]
```

[image]

This plot is fine. However, when I want to plot the figure below:

```
Plot3D[{Im[F],-Im[F]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
Mesh -> None, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][z + 0.5]],  
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
ViewPoint -> {2, -2, 1.5}]
```

[image]

**There is a gap in the upper surface (the white line). Is there any way to remove the gap to make the upper surface smooth?**

Maybe one solution is to use Piecewise to rewrite the function for the upper surface. However, I don't want yo use this method, because my further project needs to plot 4 such surfaces, which is difficult to use Piecewise.

Another solution is using "Exclusions -> None". However, when the figure is rotated, the figure is bad.

Any good solutions?

Answer (score 7):

### Warning: dirty hacky solution ahead

Just take the y values that are close to zero and make them equal to zero. 
 If `plot` is defined as in the OP, then

```
plot /. {x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {x, Chop[y, .01], z}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What is the definition of plot and what is OP?

Comment: @QiZhong OP = "original post", i.e. `plot` refers to the `Plot3D` code you used.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `ContourPlot3D`:

```
ContourPlot3D[z^2 == Im[F]^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -0.5, 0.5}, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][z + 0.5]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ViewPoint -> {2, -2, 1.5}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.4}]
```

[image]

Comment: This can work. But one disadvantage: it seems this method will use longer CPU time. And I can feel the display is not smooth(it needs time to run the code) when I rotate the figure, compared with using Plot3D.

Answer (score 2):

A dirty hack would be to draw two parametric stripes along the exclusions with the same coloring:

```
F[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := Im@Sqrt[x^2 + (y + I/2)^2]

Show[
 Plot3D[{F[x, y], -F[x, y]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][z + 0.5]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ViewPoint -> {2, -2, 1.5}, 
  Exclusions -> y == 0],
 ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, F[x, 0]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -0.01, 0.01}, 
  Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][F[x, 0] + 0.5]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Exclusions -> None],
 ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, -F[x, 0]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -0.01, 0.01}, 
  Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"][-F[x, 0] + 0.5]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Exclusions -> None]
 ]
```

[image]